# Is it wrong to intersect mesh objects together?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a decent amount of experience in Blender, however I have a question.

Is it wrong to have two objects intersecting each other? For example: If I was making a table and the legs were a different object, I would try to place them underneath the actual table, but instead of precisely measuring the pixels and attempting to align it perfectly, I would put the legs directly over the table so that they are embedded deeply into the table.

This is how I have been working in Blender currently, but I am worried that it could lead to some problems in the future.

Comment: The way this question is currently phrased, makes it "opinion-based". I'm afraid fixing that issue will still make it unfit for this site ("needs more focus"). As Robin Betts says, what matters in the end is the rendered pixel, so if what you're doing works, then it's good enough. If it bites you in future (for example, having the leg start exactly at bottom table's surface and the origin being there too, will allow you to scale that leg without worrying it will protrude through the table) then you will learn one case in which you should care about that...

Comment: It's really subjective, but unless you're doing millimetric work for which you should use a specialized CAD software instead of Blender, there shouldn't be any noticeable impact render-wise. I noticed it behaved badly in Autocad 3D renderer but it's bad for multiple other reasons so...